# R: Efficiently find the correct range my value fits in

Tags: r, performance

I have a huge table filled with ranges (2 columns), i.e. min and max:

> 1 , 5
>
> 6 , 10
>
> 11 , 15

and so on. I'd like a function that, given a number, would return both boundaries of the correct range. Say I input f(12), I'd like back 11 and 15.

I'd like some help how to build that in R. It has to be efficient because the table is relatively big (1M rows).

Comment: `findInterval` is sort of the obvious tool here.

Comment: @joran `findInterval` searches a single sorted vector.  So it won't work in this case where there isn't a single sorted vector. The requirement here is to search a set of ranges. IIUC.

Comment: @MattDowle Rereading it, I think you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the new non-equi joins feature available in the current development version of data.table, v1.9.7:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
foo <- function(x, y) {
    x = setDT(list(x=x))                     # convert to data.table
    x[y, on=.(x >= V1, x <= V2), nomatch=0L] # perform a conditional join
}
foo(12, dt)
#     x x.1
# 1: 11  15
```

where:

```
dt = fread('1,5\n6,10\n11,15\n')
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  5
# 2:  6 10
# 3: 11 15
```

See installation instructions for devel version [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

---

Note that for repetitive calls, it might not be efficient due to the call overhead to `[.data.table`. Suppose you'd like to get all the interval ranges for inputs, `3,4,12,19`, then I'd do it like this:

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.7+
x = data.table(x=c(3,4,12,19), id = 1:4)
x[dt, on=.(x >= V1, x <= V2), nomatch=0L]
#     x id x.1
# 1:  1  1   5
# 2:  1  2   5
# 3: 11  3  15
```

The first value (id=1) is in [1,5] and so is the second value (id=2). The 3rd is in [11,15]. Fourth is not in the result due to `nomatch=0`.